# How many lines and circles are needed to construct the 65537-gon (known lower bounds)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, recreational-mathematics, geometric-construction, popular-math

Johann Gustav Hermes went into exile for 10 years trying to find and write down a procedure for the construction of a regular 65537-agon only using a compass and a straightedge (and a pencil). He published a method for this in 1894, the paper being over 200 pages long.
My question is approximately how many circles and lines would be needed for such a construction (and if anyone knows, in *his* construction). Specifically I'm looking for lower bounds.

Comment: [This page](http://facstaff.susqu.edu/brakke/constructions/big-gon.htm) has a file that uses 1141 quadratic equation solutions.

Comment: Yes, and at most how many circles and lines are actually required for the solution to these...

Comment: At minimum you need no lines at all (and a lot of circles) as per the Mohr-Mascheroni Theorem.  At minimum you need at least one circle (and a lot of lines) as per the Poncelet-Steiner Theorem.  The Wikipedias page on the 65537-gon has an animated gif showing the construction using both compass and straightedge, but its too fast to comprehend.

Comment: I actually believe that among Fermat primes 17 is as high as you can go in practice with commonly available drafting equipment.